# SmartGit "The selected directory could not be created."

Tags: linux, git, debian, bitbucket, smartgit

I'm getting "The selected directory could not be created.", "Please verify whether you have the required permissions." when trying to create a directory to copy my Git project at Bitbucket to. I'm new to using Git, SmartGit and Bitbucket, I've never used any version control before.

[image: Image of my problem]

Comment: I've decided to just use git on the command line instead.

Comment: Did you have the necessary file system permissions?